# How to remove exit(0) pop-up in Python IDLE?

Tags: python, exit, python-idle, exit-code

I am trying to run some code on Python IDLE, but when I use `exit()` I am getting a pop-up. How can I remove this pop-up?

```
print "hi"
exit(-1)
```

[image: Pop-up]

Comment: Why do you use `exit()`?

Comment: @Alex.S I am trying a IF condition (Validation ) if it fails I need to exit program

Comment: I am surprised that you do not get NameError as I thought `help`, `quit`, and `exit` were only defined in interactive mode.  The fact that `print(help)` prints `Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.` suggests that this was once true.  In any case, the three functions are added by the default site module but you cannot count on them always being present. The  sys.exit function, as suggested by Alex, will always be present.

Comment: Since your code does not include `>>> ` prompts, I assume that you ran it from the editor.  If so, I consider the box a bug.  `Run Module  F5` is usually the equivalent of `python -i -m <filename>`.  Doing this would result in a SystemExit traceback followed by a prompt, just as with `python -i -c "exit()"`.  I added this to my list of things to change.

Comment: @TerryJanReddy Yes,you are right I ran in editor only.But I am not sure its bug or as per design( I am using `python 2.7.10`). I tried same in `pycharm` I didn't got any pop-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `exit()` from `sys` module.

```
import sys

# your cool code here

sys.exit(0) # stops the program without a pop-up
```

For example in an `if`:

```
import sys

x = 2
if x > 1:
    print "x > 1"
    sys.exit()
else:
    print x
```